# Keycloak Add user's name in email theme template

Tags: email, themes, keycloak

I am creating an email theme for keycloak.
So, when a user forgets their password and requests for a link to reset it; an email is sent to the user.

Now, I am cutomizing the email that he/she gets. I want to add the user's name.
Can I do that?

I do have access to variables including:
link to reset password
link expiration time
realm name

How do I get the user's name so that the email template says

Hello John,

blah blah blah

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can add *`user.username`* in  your  `.ftl`  file

open `(email/text) *.ftl` file and add *user.username* as one of the parameter  like

```
${msg("passwordResetBody",link, linkExpiration, realmName,user.username)}
```

and then update actual message body at (email/messages/messages_en.properties) with parameter number  like {2} or {3}  (in this case it is {3} )

Comment: user.username did not work but 
user.getUsername() did.

Comment: @Ishita How much it is safe to send username and password reset details in the same email,what if email sent to wrong emailid?

Comment: would first name be user.firstName?

Comment: @Jebanisa for firstname you can use `user.getFirstName()` check more here https://codehumsafar.wordpress.com/2018/09/24/keycloak-get-username-first-name-last-name-and-email-in-email-theme-template/